# Openshift down after restore database of drupal 7

Tags: database, drupal, openshift

i create drupal scalable app on openshift using there own quick start drupal , then add my modules and theme by linking folder to drupal and active , 
i use backup/migrate module for restoring my backup , but after doing app down doe layer 7 error code 500  ,i set gear limit for 1 but not fixed . 
i check logs : 
[WARNING] 062/120200 (450117) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 500, info: "HTTP s
tatus check returned code <3C>500<3E>", check duration: 516ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0
requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
 php log : 
[Wed Mar 04 10:46:21 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.10.83.1:8080

i gave this error for run my own drupal but quickstart work fine until restore database !

Answer (score 1):

This part...

"Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.10.83.1:8080"

...suggests that you pushed the development version to the server.  You'd think that the IP address would be a public one and that it would bind to port 80 rather than 8080.

My server.js has code like this...

```
        //  Set the environment variables we need.
    self.ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
    self.port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

    if (typeof self.ipaddress === "undefined") {
        //  Log errors on OpenShift but continue w/ 127.0.0.1 - this
        //  allows us to run/test the app locally.
        console.warn('No OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP var, using 127.0.0.1');
        self.ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
    };
    ...
    self.app.listen(self.port, self.ipaddress, function() {
        console.log('%s: WebApp started on %s:%d ...',
                    Date(Date.now() ), self.ipaddress, self.port);
    });
```

I wouldn't suggest using this code directly, I'm just indicating that the app should conditionally listen to either a local (private) IP address/port combination or to a remote (public) IP address/port combination.  You'd use the existence of that process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP environment variable to know that you're running there on production under a Node.Js setup.  Your own Drupal gear would have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a force stop & start, it's also possible that you hard coded the ip address somewhere in your application and need to change it to use the environment variables instead, since your new gear has a different ip address.